# Dynamically Populating an Oracle Cursor in a Stored Procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I need to dynamically populate an Oracle cursor (Oracle 10g).  The SQL statement changes, based off of the input value to pull from different tables, and columns.  What I don't want to do is have to maintain a temporary table that I truncate and load everytime the sproc is executed.  Here is what I am currently doing, but if there is another alternative I would appreciate the help:

**Stored Procedure**

```
    PROCEDURE Get_Type_One_Polygon_Values(in_role VARCHAR2, rc_generic OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as
BEGIN        

        execute immediate 'truncate table teamchk.temp_type_one_roles';

        execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TEAMCHK.TEMP_TYPE_ONE_ROLES ' || 
                          'SELECT ' || in_role || '_POLY_ID, ' || in_role || '_POLY_NAME ' ||      
                          'FROM TEAMCHK.' || in_role;        

        open rc_generic for                           
        select * from teamchk.temp_type_one_roles;

END;
```

**Temp Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE TEAMCHK.TEMP_TYPE_ONE_ROLES
(
    ROLE_ID     NUMERIC(38,0),
    ROLE_NAME   VARCHAR2(75)        
);
```

Comment: This was just the answer I needed.  I'm not sure why I overlooked that!

Comment: by the way, a global temporary table generally never needs to be truncated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy, you can use [dynamic cursors](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/cursors/dynamic.html)...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Get_Type_One_Polygon_Values
(in_role VARCHAR2, rc_generic OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as
sql varchar2(100);
BEGIN        
            sql :='SELECT ' || in_role || '_POLY_ID, ' 
                 || in_role || '_POLY_NAME '
                 || 'FROM TEAMCHK.' || in_role;        

            open rc_generic for sql;
END;
```

It may be beneficial to use column aliases POLY_ID and POLY_NAME to unify them all in the refcursor.